# How to use distinct inside concat_ws() in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In mySQL I have a table:

| id | name | code1 | code2 | code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | aaa | aaa | a |
| 2 | Ryan | bb | bbb | b |
| 3 | Ted | c | c | cc |

expected output:

| id | name | concat_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | aaa/a |
| 2 | Ryan | bb/bbb/b |
| 3 | Ted | c/cc |

I tried the below query:

```
select
  id,
  name,
  concat_ws("/",NULLIF(code1,""),NULLIF(code2,""),NULLIF(code3,"")) as concat_code
from
  table1
group by id
```

But it gives wrong output:

| id | name | concat_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | aaa/aaa/a |
| 2 | Ryan | bb/bbb/b |
| 3 | Ted | c/c/cc |

How can I use the distinct combination inside concat_ws()?

Comment: Consider revising your schema

Answer (score 1):

This is one example of why having columns foo1, foo2, etc is bad database design; there should be a separate table in a one to many relationship with the original table with one foo value in each row.  As is, you have to basically emulate that with unions:

```
select id, name, group_concat(distinct codes.code separator '/')
from table1
join (
    select id,NULLIF(code1,"") as code from table1
    union all
    select id,NULLIF(code2,"") from table1
    union all
    select id,NULLIF(code3,"") from table1
) codes using (id)
group by id
```

or use a convoluted expression for code2, code3, etc that returns null if the code matches any of the previous codes in your concat_ws call.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but for other people googling: try:

```
SELECT id, name, 
    CONCAT_WS("/",
        NULLIF(code1,""),
        CASE WHEN code2 NOT IN ('', code1) THEN code2 END, 
        CASE WHEN code3 NOT IN ('', code1, code2) THEN code3 END
    ) AS concat_code
FROM table1
```

The CASE is functioning as a NULLIF with multiple string values, some being the previous values to prevent duplicates.

I left out the GROUP BY id since id seems to be the primary key, that makes that statement useless.